# parser.y error with union structure

Tags: c, parsing, bison

So, I'm having problems with my parser.y with a compiler that I'm building. The error is saying I don't have a member inside of a union or structure, which it is. Here is the error code I've received:

```
parser.y:123: error: request for member ‘funcName’ in something not a structure or union
```

Then with the code that is inside my parser.y file:

```
%union {
    int val;
    char *funcName;
}

%token <funcName> ID
```

And here is where I'm trying to use the union in my parser.y file:

```
f_def: FUNCTION ID '(' arg_list ')' ':' type '{' stat_list '}' 
{create_function_info_item(&headFunctionInfo, func_arg_list_count(), $2.funcName);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokens have the type of whichever union member you assigned to them with the `%token` declaration - not the union type itself. So `$2` has type `char*` and you don't need the `.funcName` - it already holds the value of the `funcName` member.

Comment: I'm still slightly confused. I'm just trying to pass the $2 char of the function name. Cause I'm building a structure that holds all function info to check things in my .c file.

Comment: @pmac89 I'm saying `$2` holds the function name, which is a `char*`. You're then calling `.funcName` on that `char*`, which is a type error. As I said, the solution is to not use `.funcName` on it.